# Cannot Login Using Facebook After Removed The App From FB Account

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I just deleted (or revoked?) my app from my FB personal accounts Apps dan Websites settings. So, now, my app moved to Removed Tab.

[image: Facebook Account Apps and Websites Setting]

Then, I tried to logging-in via Facebook on my app. But, it gave result as shown below

[image: My App Screenshoot]

This is my code. I did exactly what documentation said in [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#usage)

```
import { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk'

...

try {
    LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(result => {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
            Toast.show('Canceled', Toast.SHORT);
            setIsLoadingButtonCanceled(false);
        } else {
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
                //... I did something here
            })
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        Toast.show('Failed', Toast.LONG);
    })
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Thanks